# Counting the binary digits of a signed 32-bit integer in c programming

Tags: c, 32-bit, signed, twos-complement

I have following function which counts the number of binary digits in an unsigned 32-bit integer.

```
uint32_t L(uint32_t in)
{
   uint32_t rc = 0;

   while (in)
   {
      rc++;
      in >>= 1;
   }

   return(rc);
}
```

Could anyone tell me please in case of signed 32-bit integer, which approach i should take ? implementing two's complement is an option. if you have any better approach, please let me know.

Comment: What's the expected answer? How many binary digits are there in -1?

Comment: yes. above function counts for unsigned 32-bit integer. i need to implement it for signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: I guess we need to assume your function actually returns a value...

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
uint32_t count_bits(int32_t in)
{
   uint32_t unsigned_in = (uint32_t) in;
   uint32_t rc = 0;

   while (unsigned_in)
   {
      rc++;
      unsigned_in >>= 1;
   }

   return(rc);
}
```

Just convert the *signed int* into an *unsigned* one and do the same thing as before.

BTW: I guess you know that - unless your processor has a special instruction for it and you have access to it - one of the fastest implementation of counting the bits is:

```
int count_bits(unsigned x) {
   x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0xffffffff);
   x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
   x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
   x = x + (x >> 8);
   x = x + (x >> 16);
   return x & 0x0000003f;
}
```

It's not the fastest though...

Comment: i tried your first approach, it always shows 32 in case of negative value. is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Just reuse the function you defined as is:

```
int32_t bla = /* ... */;
uin32_t count;

count = L(bla);
```

You can cast `bla` to `uint32_t` (i.e., `L((uint32_t) bla);`) to make the conversion explicit, but it's not required by C.

If you are using `gcc`, it already provides fast implementations of functions to count bits and you can use them:

```
int __builtin_popcount (unsigned int x);
int __builtin_popcountl (unsigned long);
int __builtin_popcountll (unsigned long long);
```

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: I think the OP means "any digit", not just "1-digits". But then again, I don't think the OP understands the question at all; he's been cranking out "how to do X for signed integers" en masse all day.

Answer (score 0):

Your negative number always shows 32 because the first digit of a signed negative integer is 1. A `UInt4` of `1000 = 16` but an `Int4` of `1000 = -8`, an `Int4` of `1001 = -7`, and `Int4` of `1010 = -6` etc...

Since the first digit in an `Int32` is meaningful rather just a bit of padding, you cannot really ignore it.